# Transforming sphere equation to least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, least-squares

The equation of a sphere is:

$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = r2$$

I would like to solve a system of these equations, with $n$ spheres and $3$ unknowns $(x, y, z)$.

For least squares, generally people use the formula

$Ax = b$

However, with the equation of a sphere, i think it looks more like

$A-x = b$

Could someone help me rewrite the sphere equations into

$Ax = b$

if this is possible, and if not explain to me why its not possible?
I'm new to linear algebra.

Comment: $A$ is a matrix for you? In this case, you want to rewrite a formula quadratic in $x$, $y$ and $z$ in a linear one and that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks, yes, A will be a matrix, probably with all the centers of the spheres. b will be the radii of the spheres.

Could you perhaps elaborate a little bit on your answer?

Comment: Of course and also welcome to MSE! Taking a matrix equation $Ax=b$ with vectors $x$ and $b$ (I would usw a different symbol for the vector $x$, if that also denotes its first component), you *only* get linear expressions in the coordinates $x$, $y$ and $z$ like $1\cdot x+7\cdot y+2\cdot z=9$ for example. The equation for the sphere in the other hand contains terms of the Form $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! your answer makes a lot more sense to me now :). Do you perhaps have a proposed alternative method for solving Ax=b for quadratic equations?

Comment: There is indeed a way to shorten your equation: You could use the $2$-norm, if you already know what that means. For a vector, the $p$-norm gives you the $p$-th root of the sum of the $p$-th exponents of all components. For example, the $1$-norm is just the sum of all components, while the $2$-norm gives you the euclidean distance. Hence you can describe a sphere with radius $r$ around the point $a$ with the equation $\|x-a\|_2=r$.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I am not quite sure what you mean with the p-norm. Suppose I have a sphere centered at 2, 4, 5. the norm1 would be (2+4+5) = 11, and the norm2 would be the distance between point x and the sphere?

Comment: The $p$-norm of a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is $\|(x,y,z)\|_p=\sqrt[p]{x_1^p+x_2^p+x_3^p}$. In your case, the center of the sphere is $a=(2,4,5)$, but you don't need $\|a\|_2$ to describe the sphere, but $\|x-a\|_2=r$, meaning the euclidean distance between $a$ and $x$ is exactly $r$. ($\|x-a\|_1=r$ would describe a cube.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a least square sense, the problem is a bit more difficult than it looks since the distance from a point to the sphere is
$$d=\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2}- r$$ So, what you need is to minimize
$$\Phi(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}- r_i\right)^2$$ which is not very simple (hightly nonlinear) and you need good initial estimates.

You considered to minimize
$$\Psi(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left((x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2- r_i^2\right)^2$$ which, again, is not so easy.

So, consider each equation
$$f_i=(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2- r_i^2$$ and build the $\color{red}{\frac{n(n-1)}2}$ equations $(f_i-f_j)$, $i$ going from $1$ to $(n-1)$ and $j$ from $i$ to $n$.

Expanding, each of these equations will write
$$2(a_j-a_i)x+2(b_j-b_i)y+2(c_j-c_i)z=(a_j^2+b_j^2+c_j^2-r_j^2)-(a_i^2+b_i^2+c_i^2-r_i^2)$$ which is now a linear system (easy to solve).

This gives you the guesses $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to start with for the minimization of $\Phi(x,y,z)$. If there is not too much noise in the data, you could even use Newton-Raphson method with numerical derivatives.

$$\frac {\partial \Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x-a_i)\left(\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}- r_i\right) }{\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}}$$
$$\frac {\partial \Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial y}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(y-b_i)\left(\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}- r_i\right) }{\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}}$$
$$\frac {\partial \Phi(x,y,z)}{\partial z}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(z-c_i)\left(\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}- r_i\right) }{\sqrt{(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. So if I understand this correctly, suppose I have 12 spheres, I would write "2(a0 - a1)x + 2(b0 - b1)y + 2(b0 - b1)z" from 0-11 and get a 3x6 matrix A, which I solve with the right part of the equation you mentioned?

Comment: For $12$ sphères you start with $66$equations for three variables

Comment: So for example, I would compare equation 0 with 1-11, equation 1 with 0 and 2-11, etc... ? I am not quite sure how to build the matrix A with this setup

Comment: Also, about the derivatives for the newton method. Am I right that the equation for derivative.x would be "((pos.x - sphere_i.x) * ((sqrt(distance(pos, sphere_i) - radius_i)) / (sqrt(distance(pos, sphere_i))" ?

Comment: I am accepting this answer, since 2(aj-ai)x...etc seems to work as Ax=b, and produces quite decent results in a lot of cases. It's not perfect though, so i would like to try out your newton method approach. Could you meaby explain what the error function would be for the derivatives with your approach?

Comment: @Tea-F-Tea. This preliminary step must work. It is similar to the multilateration problem. Now, you have the estimates and the three equations to solve. Just use numerical  central derivatives $(\Delta x=0.001 x)$. Let me know about your progress, please. Cheers :-)